# Read JSON inside a text file using spark and Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, text

I have a text file which has JSON data something like this:

```
{
  "element" : value,
  "id" : value,
  "total" : []
}
{
  "element" : value,
  "id" : value,
  "total: []
}
```

All the JSON are new line separated.

I am trying to load all the text files data into a temp view :

```
sqlContext.read.textFiles("/path").createOrReplaceTempView("result")

val data = sqlContext.sql("select * from result").collect()
```

Result:

```
[{"element" : value,"id" : value,"total" : [] }]
[{"element" : value,"id" : value, "total" : []}]
```

I need to extract the id and the total related to it.

Is there a way in spark to handle this?

Comment: can you also add what you get when showing the data from `result` view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Spark SQL each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON otherwise the computation fails.

However you can try this

```
spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("path to json").values)
```

or

```
spark.read.option("wholeFile", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json("path to json")
```

This should convert the json to the dataframe.

Comment: This .values? what is this. Do you mean the values inside json?

Comment: spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("path to json") will return an RDD. .values selecting the value of the rdd from that. Also I have updated the answer with options for spark 2.2

Comment: Thanks man!! It worked like a charm.. :) :) (The 2.2 version helped.. )

Answer (score 1):

Given input file with `json` data as

```
{
  "element" : value,
  "id" : value,
  "total" : []
}
{
  "element" : value,
  "id" : value,
  "total: []
}
```

which is **not** a valid json to be converted to a `dataframe`, so you have to convert the data into *valid spark readable json format*.

```
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("path to the json file")

val validJsonRdd = rdd.flatMap(_._2.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "").replace(":value", ":\"value\"").replace("}{", "}\n{").split("\n"))
```

Above step would work only if you have **value string without inverted commas** in element and id fields. Otherwise you can modify it according to your needs.

Next step is to convert into `dataframe` using `sqlcontext`.

```
 val df = sqlContext.read.json(validJsonRdd)
```

which should result to

```
+-------+-----+-----+
|element|id   |total|
+-------+-----+-----+
|value  |value|[]   |
|value  |value|[]   |
+-------+-----+-----+
```

now you should be able to select `id` and respective `totals` and play with them

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: @this works out for a small data set. But if the dataset is huge. Converting all the data to valid JsonRDD will take a lot of time.

Comment: Since my text file has already the json objects defined. Can't i read them directly?

Comment: You can but you'll have to write a JSON parser because Spark doesn't support the type of JSON you have.

Comment: @philantrovert Any help/code sample. Never written a parser in Scala. :(

Comment: @abhi5800, did you try it in your huge dataset? how much data you have?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Yes i tried this method on the 1.8GB dataset. It took ages. I had to stop it in between. :(

Comment: Hi @RameshMaharjan, thank you this really helped me for small data set  less than 1.5 GB. Can you please help how to handle for large JSON files > 2GB....I am facing same issues if I process for more than 2 GB data jobs are getting failed with OOO.... do we have any alternative approach handle Huge JSON files for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this, as it took some time to understand it, when querying for something nested inside `totals` you may have to use the "explode" method:

```
Dataset<Row> socials = sparkSession
            .read()
            .option("multiLine", true)
            .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
            .json(<path to file>).cache();

socials.select(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(socials.col("total")).as("t")).where("t.<some nested column under total> = 'foo'").toJSON().collectAsList();
```

This is for Java Spark but hope the explode method be of some help.